# Weird C stack memory overrides

Tags: c++, c, memory, gdb

I am implementing a version of malloc and free for practice. So, I have a static char array of a fixed length (10000). Then, I implemented a struct memblock that holds information like size of the block, if it is free...

The way I am implementing malloc is such that I put small blocks (< 8 bytes) to the front of the char array and larger ones to the other end. So, I am basically using two linked lists to link the blocks in front and blocks in back. However, I am having weird problems with initializing the lists (on first call of malloc).

This is my code:

```
#define MEMSIZE 10000 // this is the maximum size of the char * array
#define BLOCKSIZE sizeof(memblock) // size of the memblock struct

static char memory[MEMSIZE]; // array to store all the memory
static int init; // checks if memory is initialized
static memblock root; // general ptr that deals with both smallroot and bigroot
static memblock smallroot, bigroot; // pointers to storage of small memory blocks and bigger blocks


void initRoots(size_t size, char* fileName, int lineNum)
{
  smallroot = (memblock)memory;
  smallroot->prev = smallroot->next = 0;
  smallroot->size = MEMSIZE - 2 * BLOCKSIZE;
  smallroot->isFree = 1;
  smallroot->file = fileName;
  smallroot->lineNum = lineNum;

  bigroot = (memblock)(((char *)memory) + MEMSIZE - BLOCKSIZE - 1);
  bigroot->prev = bigroot->next = 0;
  bigroot->size = MEMSIZE - 2 * BLOCKSIZE;
  bigroot->isFree = 1;
  bigroot->file = fileName;
  bigroot->lineNum = lineNum;
  init = 1;
}
```

I used GDB to see where I am getting a Seg Fault. It happens when bigroot->next = 0; is executed. This somehow sets smallroot to 0. What is more weird? If I set bigroot->next = 0x123, then smallroot becomes 0x1. If I set 0x1234, then it becomes 0x12. It is setting smallroot to the value of bigroot->next's value excluding its last two bits. I really don't understand how this is happening!

This is the definition of memblock:

```
typedef struct memblock_* memblock;

struct memblock_ {
  struct memblock_ *prev, *next;  // pointers to next and previous blocks
  /* size: size of allocated memory
    isFree: 0 if not free, 1 if free
    lineNum: line number of user's file where malloc was invoked
  */
  size_t size, isFree, lineNum;
  char* file; // user's file name where the block was malloced
};
```

Comment: You mean last 2 nibbles, or last byte.  Not last 2 bits.

Comment: Could you please add the definition of `memblock`, it's hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: You really should care about alignment.

Comment: What do you mean by alignment? If anyone wants the entire source, I can post a link to that. I really can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> `#define BLOCKSIZE sizeof(memblock) // size of the memblock struct`

You want:

```
#define BLOCKSIZE sizeof(*memblock) // size of the memblock_ struct
```

Also the `-1` here is bogus (creates mis-aligned pointer):

```
bigroot = (memblock)(((char *)memory) + MEMSIZE - BLOCKSIZE - 1);
```

> Actually, I am storing the pointer to the memblock in the memory array. The values of memblock are stored in stack.

No, they are not. The `smallroot` and `bigroot` *clearly* point into the array itself.

Comment: Actually, I would not like to do it this way because I want to store only the pointer to memblock on the char array ("memory"). That would point to the actual struct in the stack. Your way would make occupy a lot of space of the array (it has only 10000 bytes). And smallroot and bigroot are pointers of type (struct memblock_ *)

Comment: @1729 If you want to store your `struct memblock_`s somewhere else, you have the power to do so. But that is not what your code *currently* does, and as AnT already told you, that's the root of your (current) problem.

Comment: I thought about storing `struct memblock_` seperately in a linked list. I thought a static variable could do that. But, is there any way I could achieve that because I am supposed to implement malloc? I cannot use malloc to make a linked list.